# How do we ensure knowledge articles are not shared between communities?

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge

I am working with an org that has two communities. Users in both communities have the ability to search for knowledge articles; however when a customer searches for an article in their community they see knowledge articles from the other community as well. Customers from each community have the same profile.

Is there a way to assign knowledge articles to a specific community so that they do not appear in others?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement Data Categories for your articles for this. The visibility to the knowledge articles is governed by [Data Categories](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/set-up-salesforce-knowledge/create-and-customize-data-categories) for community users.

Take a look into the article [who sees what in communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_visibility.htm&type=5) on how article visibility is controlled.

If your community has roles (meaning it should leverage communities plus or partner commuity licenses) then data categories visibility can be governed by roles.

In case of customer community license data category visibility can be set to custom and you can have a permission set with proper data category assigned and control the visibility.